# Android: Global Key Listener

Tags: android, keyboard, listener, global, counter

I am writing an android app which will record the frequency and timestamps of when a user is using their keyboards (soft or hard) (Example: a parent checking to see if their child was texting during school by giving them timestamps and frequency of key presses). This wouldn't need to know what was being typed, just when something was typed. It would also need to function regardless of what app was using the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, except perhaps via custom firmware.